# элемент в элементе (onсlick)

Tags: javascript, css

При клике на окно срабатывает и фон.
Можно ли с помощью стилей добиться нажатий только на один элемент?

```css
background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

window {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<background onclick='console.log("background")'>
  <window onclick='console.log("window")'>Content</window>
</background>
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста: ради чего Вы хотите добиться такой абсурдной цели?

Comment: @yar85, ради интереса. Может кто сталкивался с таким и я хотел бы знать почему браузер так себя ведёт, когда за одним стоит другой и клик работает на оба элемента

Comment: Браузер так себя ведет потому что он реализует стандарт. Передача события элементам выше, называется всплытием событий (event bubbling), так оно и задумано. Остановить всплытие можно только с помощью JavaScript. Единственное, что можно сделать с событиями мыши посредством CSS - это запретить элементу реагировать на них (используя `pointer-events: none`), но на всплытие это никак не влияет. Думаю, существуют какие-то хаки через обертки и трансформ, но фу так делать (при том что это реализуется лишь одной строкой на JS - незачем усложнять и костылить).

Comment: С помощью "стилей" фон может притвориться, что он фон, не являясь родительским элементом :)

Comment: @vp_arth, то есть `translate` плюс `z-index`? С этим связано множество потенциальных проблем, имхо))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

```
css - clip-path
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

2.

```
<window onclick='console.log("window");event.stopPropagation();'>Content</window>
```

*Update*

Минутку, я, кажется, рано возгордился. Похоже, дочерние элементы тоже обрезаются родительским клип-регионом. Надо подумать.

Comment: Аяяй, молодой человек, читайте вопрос внимательнее)  
Я бы хотел знать можно ли такое провернуть с помощью стилей)  
А за js плюсик, спасибо)

Comment: Igor, а  чем именно помогает в данном случае `css - clip-path `?

Comment: @Air Можно описать полигон, не включающий внутренний элемент, и назначить его как `clip-path`. События мыши не будут приходить в родителя, если мышь - не внутри клип-региона.

Comment: Точнее они будут игнорироваться? В дедушку без clip же всплывёт событие?

Comment: @vp_arth Совершенно верно. Дальше (выше по DOM-дереву, если считать, что оно растет вниз) все будет как обычно.

Comment: @Igor, классная штука, не знал...

Comment: @Igor, это просто гениально!

Comment: @yar85 Ну что Вы! (краснеет)